# Как был реализован такой эффект

Tags: javascript, html, css

При скролле был реализован эффект галереи, впервые увидел данный эффект.

И не смог найти никакой информации толком, а сам весь блок оборачивается в `canvas`.

Нашел что-то похожее `locomotive scroll`.

Ссылка на сайт - https://bien-joue.ca/fr/

Comment: на сайте используется  pixiJS https://pixijs.io/examples/

Answer (score -1):

Достичь данного эффекта вам поможет библиотека [PixiJS](https://www.pixijs.com/)

Comment: Добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! Пожалуйста, оставляйте более развёрнутые ответы: постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию, изложите свои предложения. Возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше. Дополнить ответ можно, нажав "править" https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer